# Grub does not boot Linux automatically, but editing the command line works

Tags: linux, boot, grub2

I have 2 hard-discs on my computer.
On the first one I installed Windows 7 with Linux (Ubuntu)- with different partitions.

At the beginning at booting I had the [option to choose Linux/Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB#/media/File:GRUB_screenshot.png).

But now, I have a problem with GRUB.
When booting, I have [this screen](http://www.upfile.co.il/preview/271330252/b5eb1e7975b4b0875900e448001eb0c0_PFJYKtxPOcWuCm5pftiH2g%3D%3D.html).
I managed to load Linux with command-line, that loads the kernel manually.

It seems that I have a problem with the `grub.cfg` file.

What is the best way to fix `grub.cfg`? So that when booting I will have the option to choose Linux/Windows 7 as before.

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
set default="Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)"

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}

function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos6'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ]; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd' {
recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos6'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-22-generic root=UUID=fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-22-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.11.0-22-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.11.0-22-generic-advanced-fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd' {
    recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.11.0-22-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-22-generic root=UUID=fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-22-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.11.0-22-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.11.0-22-generic-recovery-fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd' {
    recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.11.0-22-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-22-generic root=UUID=fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-22-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.11.0-20-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.11.0-20-generic-advanced-fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd' {
    recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.11.0-20-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-20-generic root=UUID=fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-20-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.11.0-20-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.11.0-20-generic-recovery-fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd' {
    recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.11.0-20-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-20-generic root=UUID=fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-20-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.8.0-39-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.8.0-39-generic-advanced-fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd' {
    recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.8.0-39-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-39-generic root=UUID=fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-39-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.8.0-39-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.8.0-39-generic-recovery-fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd' {
    recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.8.0-39-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-39-generic root=UUID=fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-39-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.8.0-29-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.8.0-29-generic-advanced-fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd' {
    recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.8.0-29-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-29-generic root=UUID=fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-29-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.8.0-29-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.8.0-29-generic-recovery-fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd' {
    recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.8.0-29-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-29-generic root=UUID=fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-29-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-49-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.5.0-49-generic-advanced-fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd' {
    recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.5.0-49-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-49-generic root=UUID=fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-49-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-49-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.5.0-49-generic-recovery-fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd' {
    recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.5.0-49-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-49-generic root=UUID=fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-49-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+)' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos6'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd
    fi
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin
}
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos6'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root fd566edf-db41-4063-ae41-462840d7cbcd
    fi
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-DC767B67767B4176' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  DC767B67767B4176
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root DC767B67767B4176
    fi
    chainloader +1
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

Comment: Please edit your post and use the image tool (the button to the right of the `{}` button, or the Ctrl+G keyboard shortcut) to post the screenshot. Your link on upfile.co.il isn't working for me (“Hash not okay”).

Comment: What modification did you make to the command line to make it boot?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so what you're gonna want to do is boot of a live USB of whatever Ubuntu distro. Then click on "Advanced options", go to the "GRUB location" tab, and select whatever partition GRUB is in. Then click apply. Did you set it up with UEFI or BIOS (Legacy BIOS) firmware enabled?

Comment: Im using BIOS...